# Why isn't Ghost.py loading/running my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, requirejs, ghost.py

Ghost.py is supposed to run JS: http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/

require.js gets fetched over http, but as far as I can tell it doesn't get run, since "js/main.built" never gets fetched and none of its specified JS files get loaded. It all works perfectly in a real browser.

```
In [51]: ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=60)

In [52]: page, resources = ghost.open(url)

In [53]: [r.url for r in resources]
Out[53]: 
[PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/#consume/283e6571bcecf34143cbd60f35e0464b'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/ui.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/colorpicker.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/selectize.default.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/datepicker.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/site.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/style.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/bootstrap.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/css/redactor.css'),
 PyQt4.QtCore.QUrl(u'https://example.com/js/lib/require.js')]

In [54]: ghost.con
ghost.confirm  ghost.content  

In [54]: ghost.content
Out[54]: u'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n    <title>Ving</title>\n\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redactor.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/selectize.default.css">\n    <!-- My Bug fixes / overrides to work with real app -->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">\n    <!-- Theme for uploader -->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">\n    <!-- Shims for IE support  -->\n    <!--[if lte IE 8]>\n      <script src="js/lib/html5shiv.js"></script>\n      <script src="js/lib/r2d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>\n    <![endif]-->\n  </head>\n\n  <body>\n    <div id="wrapper">\n      <header id="header" class="container"></header>\n      <div id="content" class="container"></div>\n    </div>\n    <footer id="footer" class="container"></footer>\n    <div id="modal" class="modal modal-box hide fade"></div>\n    <script data-main="js/main.built" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>\n\n  \n\n</body></html>'

In [55]:
```

I also tried loading "https://mail.google.com/":

```
In [7]: url='https://mail.google.com/'

In [8]: ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=60)

In [9]: page, resources = ghost.open(url)

In [10]: ghost.content
Out[10]: u'<html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=https://mail.google.com/mail/"></head><body><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><!--\nlocation.replace("https://mail.google.com/mail/")\n--></script></body></html>'

In [11]:
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, so I just switched to PhantomJS. Would've been nice to work in Python, but oh well.

Comment: Which browser(s) does the JS work correctly on?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome, IE. I tried other pages with JS on them and those didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

As require.js loads stuff asynchronously, you have to wait for a custom condition, e.g.:

```
g = Ghost()
g.open(url, wait=False)
page, resources = g.wait_for_text('something made by require.js')
```

Comment: The problem is the JS never gets executed. wait_for_text() didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try running ghost from a python program instead of from ipython or other interactive prompt. This seems to be an issue either with ghost or qt.